# NSURL is sometimes giving remote server not found error for few initial attempts

Tags: ios, nsurl

I have a strange problem in Objective C.

I have this code snippet. The problem is when I launch the application on Iphone or ipad for 4-5 times, I get remote server not found and after killing the app 4-5 times all goes well. Server is available and able to browse from mobile Safari.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
NSURL *scriptUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.zzzzzz-zz.zzzzzz-zzzz.com/zzzzz/"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:scriptUrl];
if (data)
{
    //COMPAS is reachable
    NSLog(@"Device is connected to the internet");
}
else
{
    //COMPAS is not reachable
    NSLog(@"Device is connected to the internet");
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(showHostAlert:) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
}
```

Comment: Like this we only can guess what's happening. You sure it's https ? Is always your server up. Are the url parameters correct each time ?

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be to get the data using an NSURLConnection or NSURLSession. Factory methods of classes like NSData, NSString etc. using the contentsOfURL do not work well except for local URLS. If there is some error while getting the data from a remote URL you can't get error status.

So go ahead and make a request using the connection or session classes and then use the data they provide when finished.
If you do not get the data then inspect the NSError object these classes will provide.

Comment: dataWithContentsOfURL is returning NULL sometimes, even if the server is up. What could be the reason?

Comment: You are requesting data from the network. It could be ANY reason. That's why these methods are not suitable for remote URLs. Give a try on my suggestion and with a couple of lines of code you should be able to diagnose what problems you have with the data delivery from your server.

Answer (score 0):

dataWithContentsOfUrl method on NSData is only available for loading data from local resources.

- You can use NSUrlRequest object using NSUrl and then use NSUrlConnection to make request.
- You can also use NSUrlSession object as well

Example to Get data synchronously:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:serverAddress]
                                cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData timeoutInterval:10];

[request setHTTPMethod: @"GET"];

NSError *requestError;
NSURLResponse *urlResponse = nil;

NSData *response1 = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&requestError];
```